# removing unnecessary crashes data

Tags: fuzzing, boofuzz

I am writing my fuzzer using boofuzer , but however when I want to only see where the app crash it show me all the db. how can I remove all unecesary data from the db. I just want every crash being log to the db instead of all database. I was testing against vulnserver

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from boofuzz import *

def main():
    csv_log = open('fuzz_results.csv', 'wb')
    fuzz_loggers = [FuzzLoggerCsv(file_handle=csv_log)] ### create a FuzzLoggerCSV object with the file handle of our csv file
    session = Session(
        target=Target(
            connection=SocketConnection("192.168.0.28", 9999, proto='tcp')
        ),
        #fuzz_loggers=fuzz_loggers,
        crash_threshold_element=1
    )

    s_initialize("trun")
    s_string("TRUN", fuzzable=False)
    s_delim(" ", fuzzable=False, name='space-1')
    s_string("FUZZ")
    s_static("\r\n\r\n")

    session.connect(s_get("trun"))

    session.fuzz()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Session argument `fuzz_db_keep_only_n_pass_cases`](https://boofuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/Session.html). The lowest you can set it is 1, so it will only save a single pass case preceding each failure.